# Using multiple conditions in pandas DataFrame gives ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data table like this:

```
       Item Colour    Item Range Item Size
789    COLOUR-BLUE    RANGE-PANT  SIZE-XXL
2507  COLOUR-BLACK   RANGE-OTHER  SIZE-XXL
2376  COLOUR-BLACK  RANGE-JACKET    SIZE-S
1378  COLOUR-WHITE   RANGE-OTHER    SIZE-L
598    COLOUR-BLUE  RANGE-JACKET    SIZE-M
1589   COLOUR-BLUE  RANGE-JACKET    SIZE-L
2580  COLOUR-BLACK   RANGE-SHIRT    SIZE-L
366    COLOUR-BLUE    RANGE-PANT  SIZE-XXL
2320  COLOUR-WHITE   RANGE-OTHER    SIZE-L
1247  COLOUR-GREEN    RANGE-PANT    SIZE-M
2224  COLOUR-BLACK  RANGE-JACKET    SIZE-L
3615  COLOUR-BLACK   RANGE-OTHER    SIZE-S
4176  COLOUR-GREEN    RANGE-PANT   SIZE-XL
1640  COLOUR-BLACK    RANGE-PANT    SIZE-S
1136  COLOUR-WHITE   RANGE-OTHER    SIZE-M
3437  COLOUR-BLACK  RANGE-JACKET    SIZE-S
4448  COLOUR-WHITE   RANGE-OTHER    SIZE-S
1188  COLOUR-WHITE   RANGE-SHIRT  SIZE-XXL
3332  COLOUR-GREEN   RANGE-OTHER    SIZE-M
1080  COLOUR-WHITE   RANGE-OTHER  SIZE-XXL
```

I want to get only the sub selection of data using the following mask:

```
mask = (df['Item Colour'] == 'COLOUR-WHITE') & (df['Item Range'] in ['RANGE-JACKET','RANGE-PANT']) & (df['Item Size'] not in ['SIZE-XXL'])
```

I tried `df[mask]` but it gives me the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How to avoid the error.

I have done this so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.drop(['Item','Item.2','Size'], inplace=True,axis=1)
df.columns = ['Item Colour', 'Item Range', 'Item Size']
print(df)

mask = (df['Item Colour'] == 'COLOUR-WHITE') & (df['Item Range'] in ['RANGE-JACKET','RANGE-PANT']) & (df['Item Size'] not in ['SIZE-XXL'])

dff = df[mask]
dff
```

**Update**
Still does not work.

```
mask =  (df['Item Colour'] == 'COLOUR-WHITE').all()\
      & (df['Item Range'] in ['RANGE-JACKET','RANGE-PANT']).all()\
      & ( ~df['Item Size'].isin(['SIZE-XXL']).all())

df[mask]
```

Comment: you need to change you `in` and `not in` statements to `pd.series.isin()`

Comment: why is @Vishnu Kunchur's answer not the accepted one? Bhishan's answer is practically the same, but later.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is coming from the way you're building your mask by checking whether items are in a list. You can do this with the `pd.Series.isin([item1, item2, ...])` Series method. So, instead of:

`df['Item Range'] in ['RANGE-JACKET','RANGE-PANT']`,

do:

`df['Item Range'].isin(['RANGE-JACKET','RANGE-PANT'])`

To negate, for the 'not in':

`df['Item Size'] not in ['SIZE-XXL']`,

you can do:

`~df['Item Size'].isin(['SIZE-XXL'])`